# Reading data file and creating objects versus loading .NET assembly with data already in it

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Assume there is some sort of data file(>5MB) you can consume this data in couple of ways, one a .Net application will read the data file and create custom objects. Second we create c# .cs file with predefined data structure with the values read from the data file. Compile the .cs file into an .dll assembly, and the .Net application will load this assembly when needed.
Would there be any advantage to use the second method where there is a need to constantly load new data into an high performance application(assuming accessing db or other cache systems are ruled out as design choices).

Comment: Is this data static or does it have to change in time?

Comment: What type of data - what about loading it into a resx? But if you're considering putting it into a DLL then its going to be static - so why not load it once at start-up and cache it in MemoryCache (one time)

Comment: This data is very dynamic in terms of size/number of data items and the value of the same data item are changing.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to see how your second scenario can be an advantage. "Keep it simple" - I'm guessing the first scenario does involve fewer operations and less programming?

Comment: yes reading data file is simple. here is some context. i have a web app, reads data files & create custom objects.Every data file contains new set of information or updated information, the app refreshes its custom objects  when new data file is available. My attempt is to look for alternate solution in which data values are already in a compiled assembly as static data structure. The application loads this assembly dynamically instead and will access the data structure instead of reading the data file to create the same data structure. I guess only way to find out is to experiment.